# Hawkular: Could not connect to Cassandra DB on LocalHost

Tags: cassandra, cql, metrics, hawkular

Im tring t build up an Hawkular Server in Windows 7 - unfortunately this server works with a Cassandra DB - ive installed the newest version and in the starting process of Hawkular I got following error:

```
14:57:20,102 ERROR [org.hawkular.alerts.bus.log] (Thread-195 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads-205387390)) HAWKALERT210009: Error accesing to DefinitionsService. Description: [java.lang.RuntimeException: Cassandra session is null]
14:57:19,843 WARN  [org.hawkular.metrics.api.jaxrs.MetricsServiceLifecycle] (metricsservice-lifecycle-thread) HAWKMETRICS200004: [18] Retrying connecting to Cassandra cluster in [2]s...
14:57:19,839 ERROR [org.hawkular.alerts.engine.log] (EE-ManagedExecutorService-default-Thread-10) HAWKALERT220009: Definitions Service error in [Triggers]. Msg: [java.lang.RuntimeException: Cassandra session is null]
14:57:20,354 ERROR [org.hawkular.alerts.bus.log] (Thread-190 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads-205387390)) HAWKALERT210009: Error accesing to DefinitionsService. Description: [com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for qu
ery failed (tried: /127.0.0.1:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: unconfigured table schema_keyspaces))]
14:57:22,104 INFO  [org.hawkular.inventory.impl.tinkerpop] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 111) HAWKINV001000: Using graph provider: org.hawkular.inventory.impl.tinkerpop.provider.TitanProvider
14:57:22,360 INFO  [org.hawkular.metrics.api.jaxrs.MetricsServiceLifecycle] (metricsservice-lifecycle-thread) HAWKMETRICS200002: Initializing metrics service
14:57:22,396 WARN  [org.hawkular.metrics.api.jaxrs.MetricsServiceLifecycle] (metricsservice-lifecycle-thread) HAWKMETRICS200003: Could not connect to Cassandra cluster - assuming its not up yet: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /127.0.0.1:9042 (com.d
atastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: unconfigured table schema_keyspaces))
14:57:22,397 WARN  [org.hawkular.metrics.api.jaxrs.MetricsServiceLifecycle] (metricsservice-lifecycle-thread) HAWKMETRICS200004: [19] Retrying connecting to Cassandra cluster in [3]s...
14:57:23,102 WARN  [org.hawkular.inventory.cdi] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 111) HAWKINV003501: Inventory backend failed to initialize in an attempt 10 of 15 with message: Could not instantiate implementation: com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.cassandra.th
rift.CassandraThriftStoreManager.
14:57:25,398 INFO  [org.hawkular.metrics.api.jaxrs.MetricsServiceLifecycle] (metricsservice-lifecycle-thread) HAWKMETRICS200002: Initializing metrics service
14:57:25,438 WARN  [org.hawkular.metrics.api.jaxrs.MetricsServiceLifecycle] (metricsservice-lifecycle-thread) HAWKMETRICS200003: Could not connect to Cassandra cluster - assuming its not up yet: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /127.0.0.1:9042 (com.d
atastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: unconfigured table schema_keyspaces))
```

Cassandra DB is online and I can connect to localhost:9160  with the Cassandra CQL Shell - but not the hawkular server - have I forgotten something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the log, the port Hawkular is trying to use is 9042. Make sure of this setting in your `cassandra.yaml`

```
start_native_transport: true
native_transport_port: 9042
```

The port you are using (9160) is thrift port.

Answer (score 0):

I can only take a stab in the dark with such limited information.

However you said you connected to localhost:**9160**. In the log it mentions "127.0.0.1:**9042**".